# How to switch between tabs in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have created a tabs widget that contains a table widget on the first tab. Whenever a record in the table widget is selected, the focus should switch from the first tab to the second tab as this contains more detailed data regarding the record. How can I implement such a script? Is there something like

```
app.currentpage.tabs.selectedtab = ...
```

Comment: Found it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select second tab you can use this code snippet:

```javascript
// Setting selected tab index to 1 since indices are zero-based.
app.currentPage.descendants.MyTabsWidgetName.selectedTab = 1;
```

This code can be placed in `onClick` event handler of the table's row.